# how to limit page access to localhost in Python?

Tags: python, security, localhost, port

Using Python's SimpleHTTPServer, how can I make it so that the server only responds to requests that come from the local machine?

Is there a language-agnostic way to do this? Maybe by using a specific port that is not open to the public, or by telling the firewall not to allow access to that port from outside?

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879500/how-to-limit-page-access-only-to-localhost), but specific to a server written with Python's SimpleHTTPServer.

Comment: `python -m http.server --bind 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the loopback interface. `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` refers to the local address, bypasses the full networking stack, and is not accessible via the network. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)

Take the SimpleHTTPServer [example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html).

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8000

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

We can bind to a specific address, you could use the address assigned to your machine/interface, or in your case, the loopback device.

```
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("127.0.0.1", PORT), Handler)
```

You can then access the server at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` or `http://localhost:8000/`. The server will not be accessible using your machines assigned IP address, both from your local machine and via the network.

The following may provide additional information

- [ideas on specifying bind address from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268835/is-it-possible-to-run-python-simplehttpserver-on-localhost-only)
- [you might be able to programatically/dynamically filter connections by building on the example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055005/how-to-get-client-ip-from-simplehttpserver)