# How to get IP address of the client who made request to python SimpleHTTPServer?

Tags: python, server, simplehttpserver

I am setting python local server using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, I made that server publicly available using `ngrock` and have some public IP address like `http://2ee94---.ngrok.io`. Now I am making the `request` to the public IP address. I want to get IP address from request. 
But I am getting the only status in the terminal. How to get details (IP address of client) of the request.

```
HTTP Requests                                                                   
-------------                                                                   

GET  /                         200 OK                                           
GET  /                         200 OK
```

Comment: which details you want ?

Comment: IP address of the client, who is making a request to the server.

Comment: `SimpleHTTPServer` is, well, *simple*. Probably you want a more full-featured server…!?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055005/how-to-get-client-ip-from-simplehttpserver

Comment: You could use `Flask` which has the `request.remote_addr`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get client IP from SimpleHTTPServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055005/how-to-get-client-ip-from-simplehttpserver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it done after setting up my own handler class,

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer


class MyHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def handle_one_request(self):
        print(self.client_address[0])
        return SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.handle_one_request(self)

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", 8080), MyHandler)

while True:
    httpd.handle_request()
```